# подключение штрафов на сайте

Tags: html, api, https, request

Кто нибудь сталкивался с необходимостью подключения API gibdd на проверку штрафов и т.д. на сайте?

нигде не могу найти информацию по https://www.gibdd.ru/api/ - есть у кого нибудь?

Comment: Для проверки штрафов нет официального API, есть только разные сторонние платные. Мне самому нужно было такое сделать и я долго искал, но ничего путного не нашел. Можно сделать парсер сайта ГИБДД, а для разгадывания капчи использовать разные сервисы.

Answer (score 2):

На данный момент всё вполне успешно бегает через AJAX
https://xn--90adear.xn--p1ai/check/fines#fines
Можно имитировать браузер посетителя.

Или смотреть здесь:
https://xn--80aqu.xn--90adear.xn--p1ai/v2/
Вот только там можно получить судя по описанию только реквизиты подразделений.

Лучше написать в ГИБДД официальный запрос, за месяц скорей всего ответят, что не случилось с этим вопросом.

Comment: тогда это не решает вопрос

Answer (score 0):

Вроде документация все есть.

1. [гибдд.рф/api](https://xn--90adear.xn--p1ai/api/)
2. [апи.гибдд.рф](https://xn--80aqu.xn--90adear.xn--p1ai/)